# How can I dynamically render all user post images with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-hooks

I am trying to render in all user posts images in my web application with React in my `Discover` component. How can I go about doing this? This is how the objects look like in JSON:

[image]

This is what I have currently in my discover component.

Discover.jsx:

```html
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import UserPostsService from '../../services/user-post.service';
import './styles/Discover.css';

const Discover = () => {
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');
    const [photoURL, setPhotoURL] = useState('/images/user-solid.jpeg');

    useEffect(() => {
        UserPostsService.getAllPosts().then(
            (response) => {
                if (response.data.postImage)
                    setPhotoURL(response.data.post_img_complete);
            },
            (error) => {
                const _content =
                    (error.response &&
                        error.response.data &&
                        error.response.data.message) ||
                    error.message ||
                    error.toString();
                setContent(_content);
            }
        );
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className='page'>
            <div className='user-post'>
                <img src={photoURL} alt='User-Post' className='post'></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Discover;
```

I need to render each post_img_complete somehow, but I am not sure how to go about this. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to render all posts, you need to store the data array in your state. Then you can map over the state to render all posts.

I create a state named `posts`. I get the data array from response and store it in `posts` state. Now i map over the `posts` state and render each post image.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import UserPostsService from '../../services/user-post.service';
import './styles/Discover.css';

const Discover = () => {
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');
    // const [photoURL, setPhotoURL] = useState('/images/user-solid.jpeg');
    const [posts, setPosts]=useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        UserPostsService.getAllPosts().then(
            (response) => {
                if (response.data) setPosts(response.data)
            },
            (error) => {
                const _content =
                    (error.response &&
                        error.response.data &&
                        error.response.data.message) ||
                    error.message ||
                    error.toString();
                setContent(_content);
            }
        );
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className='page'>
            {posts.map((post)=>(
                <div className='user-post'>
                   <img src={post.post_img_complete} alt='User-Post' className='post'/>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Discover;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!